# Mass String Replacement in all HTML email templates via API

Tags: api, html

I have some 100 odd HTML email templates. I need to edit *all* templates to replace once string with another. (It's a HTML snippet replacement).

Is there some Salesforce API with which I can accomplish this ?
Otherwise I would've to manually download each template and replace the string and re-upload.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can work with email templates as with regular records.

```
EmailTemplate et = [SELECT Id, Body from EmailTemplate WHERE id='00X1i000000ljmvEAA'];
et.Body.replace('asdf', '1234');
update et;
```

Just write your script and execute it in [anonymous console](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=code_dev_console_execute_anonymous.htm&type=0).

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize there is something like this - Can you give me some reference to where I can find more info on this ? Where do I run this ? Which console ? Salesforce console ? Or do I need to write JavaScript code to run in nodeJS on my laptop ?

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=code_dev_console_execute_anonymous.htm&type=0

Comment: Got it, thanks.

Comment: Does Body.replace work for HTML templates ? https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/154376/99464

Comment: you can try `et.HtmlValue`